# Matrix differential equation MX' = AX+XB+C(t)

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

Here is matrix differential equation:
$$
\mu \frac {dX}{dt}=AX+XB+C(t)
$$
$$
X(0) = X_0
$$

Here $\mu$ is real diagonal matrix, $X$ is $m$ by $n$ matrix. $A$, $B$ are real square matrices of constant coefficients.

Without $\mu$ it would be standard Sylvestor Matrix ODE. I'm looking for a solution of it or maybe a method to try.

Comment: Sure an expert will weigh in. In the meantime, Is $\mu$ by chance near-identity? Then you might explore a perturbation approach.

Comment: Actually $\mu=\cos(\theta_i)$ so it starts with 1 and lowers toward -1. Usually $\mu$ mesh is equally spaced with about 80-120 point.