# Homogenous Matrix-valued ODE with left and right multiplication

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

> Considering the differential equation
>
> $X'=X \cdot A + B \cdot X$,
>
> where $A, B, X: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are matrix-valued functions.
>   What can be said about the solutions for such a differential equation?
>   Can it be reduced to a simpler case?
>   Does it have a name?

To give a bit of context:
When looking for canonical curves in the context of Cartan geometries, I came upon this differential equation.
In my case $B$ happens to be constant and $X$ is required to be of a relatively special form, namely

$X =
\begin{pmatrix}
 a^{-1} & v & -\frac{1}{2} a \langle v,v \rangle_{p,q} \\
 0      & A & -aAv \\
 0      & 0 & a
\end{pmatrix}$

for some $a: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a real valued function, $v:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a vector valued function, $A: I \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(p,q)$ an orthogonal matrix at each point in time. In particular $X$ is an upper triangular matrix with determinant $1$.

It looks very similar to the case $X'=X \cdot A$, where a solution is given by the matrix exponential, but I did not find that to be of any help so far.

Comment: Since $X \mapsto XA+BX$ is linear in $X$, there should still be a matrix exponential solution. But the matrix will be $n^2 \times n^2$. You might hope for it to be sparse.

Comment: Thank you, I was a bit confused about your answer at first, but when considering $X$ as a vector rather than a matrix by just writing all matrix entries in a column, then rewriting the ODE in terms of this new vector will be a linear ODE. This answers my question very well.

Comment: Oh and for future reference, in case anyone else is interested in it: The differential equation is called "Sylvester equation", as referenced in the math.stackexchange question "Matrix differential equation MX' = AX+XB+C(t)" here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725043/matrix-differential-equation-mx-axxbct?rq=1 . There is some theory for the general solution of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A,B$ are constant matrices, then the solution s.t. $X(0)=X_0$ is $X(t)=e^{tB}X_0e^{tA}$.

Comment: That is true and one sees very well how it generalizes to a solution for arbitrary $A$ and $B$ in the other answer I just posted. Still thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in a comment before:
An ODE of the form $X'(t)=A(t)X(t)+X(t)B(t)$ is called *Sylvester ODE*.
It is treated in "Sylvester matrix Differential Equations: Analytical and Numerical Solutions" by Laurene V. Fausett.

I will quickly copy the general solution here:
Let $Y$ be a solution of $T'=AT$ and $Z$ be a solution of $T'=TB$.
Let $C$ be any constant square matrix.
Then $X(t):=Y(t) C Z(t)$ satisfies:

$X'(t)
=Y'(t) C Z(t)+ Y(t) C Z'(t)
=A(t) Y(t) C Z(t) + Y(t) C Z(t) B(t)
=A(t) X(t) + X(t) B(t)$,

i.e. is a solution to the above mentioned ODE.
Given any initial data $X(0)=X_0$ we can choose $C$ to satisfy there data.
By the Picard-Lindelöf theorem this solution to the IVP is unique.

Comment: @ Daniel , I see that you give yourself the green chevron because you copy a part of a standard paper; my friend, you are ridiculous. Moreover, when $A$ is not a constant matrix, there is no explicit formula that gives a non-zero solution of $X'=AX$; you can only find a numerical approximation of a non-zero solution.

Comment: I am very shocked about your comment. I didn't want to break any rule. If I did something wrong, please tell me how to correct my behaviour. I copied the content from the paper, because not every user may have access to it or it might become unavailable. Also I am sorry that you do not find my answer satisfactory, however it is exactly what I was looking for. Also I believe the formula $\frac{d}{dt}e^{X(t)}=e^{X(t)}\frac{1-e^{-ad_X}}{ad_X}\cdot \frac{dX(t)}{dt}$ can help to find a solution of $X'=AX$ in special cases. I also gave you an upvote and a green checkmark.

Comment: @ Daniel , when you post a question, you ask the readers to work on your problem; then giving yourself the green chevron is a lack of respect for those who sent a reply. Of course, if you obtain several upvotes (that is not the case here), then the situation can be reconsidered. Anyway the process is inelegant. Yet, you are new on this forum and all that does not matter.

Comment: I did not mean to disrespect you. However your answer was incomplete, hence I did not give you the green checkmark. Once my question was answered, I gave a green checkmark to the complete answer, and I still can see nothing wrong with that. Still thank you for your answer and your effort and I will try my best to follow the unwritten rules of stackexchange in the future.